# python: how to annotate class functions for inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, annotations

Consider the following setup:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...  # stuff happens here

    @classmethod
    def fun(cls, *additional_args) -> 'A':
        out: A = cls(*additional_args)
        ...  # something happens to out here
        return out

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...  # more & other stuff happens here, too
```

The class "B" knows "fun" as class-method due to inheritance from class "A".
However the return type annotation of "fun" indicates "B.fun(...)" would provide an instance of "A", although it actually provides an instance of "B" itself (as it is supposed to do).
My question is: What annotations of "fun" & "out" should I have used during the definition of "fun" within class "A" such that it becomes clear that "A.fun(...)" returns an instance of "A" whereas "B.fun(...)" returns an instance of class "B"?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime a new feature "Self" (with capital letter: "S") via

```
from typing import Self
```

was introduced to address exactly this issue.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=self#typing.Self